# When did Lancastrians stop saying *by gum*?

Tags: dialects, minced-oaths

I distinctly remember from my youth in  the 1950s, the folk of Manchester and surrounds who came on holiday to Norfolk, and their expressions of *bye jove* and *by gum* - polite forms of *by God*.

But in the last fourteen years since I have been coming to Manchester to visit my daughter I have seldom, if ever heard them. Where have they gone?

Comment: “By gum” does sound old, and was perhaps not restricted to Lancaster, since I too remember it from old movies.  But I don’t know that a “where have they gone?” question can have an answer for an idiom passed out of current use.  You might still get the answer to the when part of the question, but I wouldn’t hold my breath if I were you.

Comment: Probably stayed in more rural areas. Not just a Lancashire saying - old joke that President Mugabe is a Yorkshireman because his name backwards is ee bah gum.

Comment: @Mynamite +1 Good one that.

Comment: What!!!! It's disappeared???? !!!!! Nooooo. Nobody told me about that! I'm going to go and have to chastise my GF's folks now for doing it ... Hmmm. Hmmmm. Makes you kinda ... hmmm... tiddly pom ... tiddly ... : Ey by gum but I'm cawd, Eh by gum but I'm cawd.  Me arms are like stone, my feet are like lead, and I ain't been warm since I left me bed, Eh by gum but I'm cowd, tiddly pom ...

Comment: The last recorded use of *by gum* by a Lancastrian (Peter James Lancaster III) was on July 13, 1994, at 6:37 pm GMT. He is reported to have exclaimed in disgust before passing away, "*By gum, I will* ***not*** *go the way of the Passenger Pigeon!*

Comment: No-one has mentioned 'By Jove', which is not limited to the North but is now old-fashioned. See http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2015/03/by-jove.html

Answer (score 2):

The expression is now  considered archaic but appears to be still in use in  areas in the north of England according to The Phrase Finder:

[By gum](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/82225.html):

> - Exclamation of surprise. This is an example of a minced-oath, and is a euphemism for 'By God'.

Origin:

> - It is known since the early 19th century, as in this example from James Kirke Paulding (a.k.a. 'Bull-Us, Hector'), 1815:
> - "By gum, that's jist what I want you to tell me, I swow."
>
>   - It is still in use in the north of England, although would be considered archaic elsewhere.

[NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by%20gum&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cby%20gum%3B%2Cc0) shows a decrease in usage of the expression since the 50's.

A small variant of the  expression *[Eeh by gum](http://www.bbc.co.uk/northyorkshire/voices2005/glossary/glossary.shtml)* is present in the BBC North Yorkshire Dialect.

Comment: +1. I have always associated it more with Lancashire than Yorkshire. You seem to imply that it was once heard outside the North. I was not aware of that, though I accept that a lot of what appear to be regionalisms in Britain are merely archaic hangovers of a once wider currency.

Comment: @WS2 Interesting. To me it sounds like something out of Appalachia. There are [various theories about the fossil forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appalachian_English) found in the dialects there, and among these is that they are vestiges of the language spoken by settlers of a Scots-Irish origin or of the Anglo-Scottish border dialects.